# Azure Devops Build - Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 not accepted

Tags: azure-devops, react-native, azure-pipelines-build-task

My ReactNative project for Android is being integrated and packaged using Azure Build Pipeline. It worked fine for months but a few days back I started getting this error:

> Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 not
>   accepted

I tried different Agents, but no luck.

The common solutions suggested to check-in the license files, but is there a better fix? Couldn't find much of other people talking about this, hence I assume this is not an issue with the Azure Build Pipleline.

```
[command]C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe D:\a\1\s\android\gradlew assembleRelease
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip

... 

Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 not accepted.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: suffering the same problem. No clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [temp workaround here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/432048/devops-cannot-build-our-projects-because-of-missin.html). Basically add a PowerShell step at the beginning of your build and set the license. Seems to be an issue for all Android related builds.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android SDK root folder (where tools folder exists inside it)

create licenses folder if not exists

create android-sdk-license file inside licenses folder if not exists

open android-sdk-license file as text file (with notepad)

paste following content inside the file and save it

```
8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55
d56f5187479451eabf01fb78af6dfcb131a6481e
24333f8a63b6825ea9c5514f83c2829b004d1fee
```

license location : sdkpath\licenses\android-sdk-license